# How to modify access policies in cloudsearch via boto

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto, policies

How can I change the access policies of a cloudsearch domain via boto?  Is it possible at all?

Using boto 2.6.0 I see a `get_access_policies()` method in the domain instance, but nothing for modifying the policies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That method returns an [`OptionStatus`](http://docs.pythonboto.org/en/latest/ref/cloudsearch.html#module-boto.cloudsearch.optionstatus) object. It looks like you can change the object's attributes and then call its `save()` method to modify policies.

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, that solution was also used in http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cloudsearch_tut.html

Comment: Ah, and finding one's own external IP in an EC2 instance can be done by GETting the answer for http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/public-ipv4